# Как в PostfixAdmin настроить пароли в CRAM-MD5?

Tags: postfix

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой при переносе почтового сервера Postfix + Dovecot (версия 2.2.22). На старом пароли в CRAM-MD5, ящиков около 300 шт и вручную заводить их - это долго.

При настройке и добавлении ящиков в PostfixAdmin (версия 3.0.2), следующая ошибка:

```
can't encrypt password with dovecotpw, see error log for details
```

Настройки SQL в dovecot

```
driver = mysql
connect = host=localhost dbname=postfix user=postfixuser password=qwerty
default_pass_scheme = CRAM-MD5

user_query = \
SELECT '/var/vmail/%d/%n' as home, 'maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n' as mail, \
1150 AS uid, 8 AS gid, concat('dirsize:storage=', quota) AS quota \
FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u' AND active = '1'

password_query = \
SELECT username as user, password, '/var/vmail/%d/%n' as userdb_home, \
'maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n' as userdb_mail, 1150 as userdb_uid, 8 as userdb_gid \
FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u' AND active = '1'
```

auth.conf

```
disable_plaintext_auth = no
auth_mechanisms = plain login cram-md5
#!include auth-system.conf.ext
!include auth-sql.conf.ext
```

PosftixADmin config.inc.php

```
$CONF['encrypt'] = 'dovecot:CRAM-MD5';
$CONF['authlib_default_flavor'] = 'md5raw';
$CONF['dovecotpw'] = "/usr/sbin/doveadm pw";
```